# JavaScript and returning variables to an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to return an array that will display the results in the div id.  I'm not able to return the value of the array without NaN.  I tried adding a value to the `document.getElementsByName("coins").value;` Is using `document.getElementsByName` the best option for pulling a integer from a form input.  What is the best way to display the return variables from a function in HTML5?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Problem #2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<!--
Write a JavaScript function that accepts a number of U.S. cents and
returns an array containing, respectively, the smallest number of
U.S. quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies that equal the given
amount.

Make sure to handle incorrect inputs

-->
<body>
    <h1>Problem #2:</h1>

    <form id="form" class="form">
        <input type="number" name="coins" placeholder="Enter your cents" min="0" />
        <input type="button" name="solve-val" value="Solve" onclick="chkcoin()"/>
    </form>
    <div id="answer">
        <div id="quarters">Quarters =</div>
        <div id="dimes">Dimes =</div>
        <div id="nickels">Nickels =</div>
        <div id="pennies">Pennies =</div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var coinval = (document.getElementsByName("coins")[0].value);
        var quarter, dime, nickel, penny = 0;   

        function chkcoin() {
            leftover = coinval;
            var monvalu = [25, 10, 5];
            quarter = Math.floor(leftover % monvalu[0]);
            leftover %= monvalu[0];
            dime = Math.floor(leftover % monvalu[1]);
            leftover %= monvalu[1];
            nickel = Math.floor(leftover % monvalu[2]);
            penny = leftover % monvalu[2];
            return [quarter, dime, nickel, penny];
        };
        document.getElementById("quarters").innerHTML = 'Quarters =' +   quarter;
        document.getElementById("dimes").innerHTML = nickel;
        document.getElementById("nickels").innerHTML = dime;
        document.getElementById("pennies").innerHTML = penny;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot "display" a value of an array within an element. The proper way to display an array would be to create multiple elements containing 1 value each.

When you 'return' a value to HTML it doesn't really do anything within it, however if you set a property of a certain HTML element, then the returned value could influence that property.

To further add, your return statement in the chkcoin function doesn't really do anything. You can remove it, the program will behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

[Here (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/57ooqxg2/) is a quick fix of the errors you have as in terms of why the code isn't running. I do not understand what sort of math mumbo-jumbo are you trying to pull here, but that is up to you, as far as code goes whatever you put into those variables of yours will be displayed in the HTML

**DISCLAIMER:** I personally think this is a bad way of doing things, I'd urge you to handle elements by id not name, as well as separate HTML and JS, and even preferably register event handlers instead of doing inline event handling. Do not be discouraged, this is very good for a guy that is just starting to learn!

```
function chkcoin() {    
//You need to include these lines to the 'fucntion call' because otherwise you are executing them before ever giving value to the "coins" element, thus you have NaN.
  var coinval = (document.getElementsByName("coins")[0].value);
  var quarter, dime, nickel, penny = 0;

  leftover = coinval;
  var monvalu = [25, 10, 5];
  quarter = Math.floor(leftover % monvalu[0]);
  leftover %= monvalu[0];
  dime = Math.floor(leftover % monvalu[1]);
  leftover %= monvalu[1];
  nickel = Math.floor(leftover % monvalu[2]);
  penny = leftover % monvalu[2];

  //You don't need a return statement.
  //return [quarter, dime, nickel, penny];


//You need to include these lines into the 'function call' as well because you want to update the HTML on a button press, not at the script loading.
  document.getElementById("quarters").innerHTML = 'Quarters =' + quarter;
  document.getElementById("dimes").innerHTML = nickel;
  document.getElementById("nickels").innerHTML = dime;
  document.getElementById("pennies").innerHTML = penny;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code is producing an undesired output as the code that reads the value of field "coins" is written outside the function **chkcoin()** which means it gets executed as soon as the webpage gets loaded. However, as per your requirement, you must invoke it on the **onclick event** thereby passing the user entered value and performing the desired manipulation

*Moreover, please check as there seems to be some issue with the logic as well : use Math.floor(leftover / monvalu[0]) instead of Math.floor(leftover % monvalu[0])*

The code should look like this :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Problem #2</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        </head>
        <!--
        Write a JavaScript function that accepts a number of U.S. cents and
        returns an array containing, respectively, the smallest number of
        U.S. quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies that equal the given
        amount.

        Make sure to handle incorrect inputs

        -->
        <body>
            <h1>Problem #2:</h1>

            <form id="form" class="form">
                <input type="number" name="coins" placeholder="Enter your cents" min="0" />
                <input type="button" name="solve-val" value="Solve" onclick="chkcoin()"/>
            </form>
            <div id="answer">
                <div id="quarters">Quarters =</div>
                <div id="dimes">Dimes =</div>
                <div id="nickels">Nickels =</div>
                <div id="pennies">Pennies =</div>
            </div>
            <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                function chkcoin() {
    //Read the value of **coins** on the onclick event of the button
                var coinval = (document.getElementsByName("coins")[0].value);
                var quarter, dime, nickel, penny = 0;   


                    leftover = coinval;
                    var monvalu = [25, 10, 5];
//The logic should involve division to get number of quarters in a cent and likewise
                    quarter = Math.floor(leftover / monvalu[0]);
                    leftover %= monvalu[0];
                    dime = Math.floor(leftover / monvalu[1]);
                    leftover %= monvalu[1];
                    nickel = Math.floor(leftover / monvalu[2]);
                    penny = leftover % monvalu[2];

    //Update the div elements with the value that you have computed.No need to return an array object.
                     document.getElementById("quarters").innerHTML = 'Quarters =' +   quarter;
                document.getElementById("dimes").innerHTML = 'Dimes=' + dime;
                document.getElementById("nickels").innerHTML = 'Nickel='+nickel;
                document.getElementById("pennies").innerHTML = 'Pennies='+penny;
                };

            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Note : document.getElementById() is preferred over document.getElementByName().

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use getElementById for get value of any input text. For return value It's not good way to return multiple value in same time. you can add values in HTML DOM inside your chkcoin() function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Problem #2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Problem #2:</h1>

    <form id="form" class="form">
        <input type="number" name="coins" placeholder="Enter your cents" id="txtCoins" min="0" />
        <input type="button" name="solve-val" value="Solve" onclick="chkcoin()"/>
    </form>
    <div id="answer">
        <div id="quarters">Quarters =</div>
        <div id="dimes">Dimes =</div>
        <div id="nickels">Nickels =</div>
        <div id="pennies">Pennies =</div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        function chkcoin() {
            var coinval = document.getElementById("txtCoins");
            // For jQuery you can use var coinval = $("#txtCoins").val();
            var quarter, dime, nickel, penny = 0;   
            leftover = coinval;
            var monvalu = [25, 10, 5];
            quarter = Math.floor(leftover % monvalu[0]);
            leftover %= monvalu[0];
            dime = Math.floor(leftover % monvalu[1]);
            leftover %= monvalu[1];
            nickel = Math.floor(leftover % monvalu[2]);
            penny = leftover % monvalu[2];

        document.getElementById("quarters").innerHTML = 'Quarters =' +   quarter;
        document.getElementById("dimes").innerHTML = nickel;
        document.getElementById("nickels").innerHTML = dime;
        document.getElementById("pennies").innerHTML = penny;
};
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```